# org.javalite.activejdbc.DBException: com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure due to underlying exception:

Tags: mysql, activejdbc, javalite

Getting `org.javalite.activejdbc.DBException` frequently while connecting to DB using `activejdbc**`

Please help to know why this is happening frequently??

> exception occurred while getting user :
>   org.javalite.activejdbc.DBException:
>
> com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
>   due to underlying exception: 
>       ** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** >
>       java.net.SocketException
>       MESSAGE: Connection reset by peer: socket write error>
>       STACKTRACE:>
>       java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
>         at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
>         at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
>         at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
>         at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
>         at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(Unknown Source)
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:2637)
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1554)
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1665)
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3176)
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1153)
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1266)
>         at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:353)
>         at org.javalite.activejdbc.DB.find(DB.java:505)
>         at org.javalite.activejdbc.LazyList.hydrate(LazyList.java:329)
>         at org.javalite.activejdbc.AbstractLazyList.isEmpty(AbstractLazyList.java:42)
>         at org.javalite.activejdbc.ModelDelegate.findFirst(ModelDelegate.java:223)
>         at com.nb.ats.db.model.UserModel.findFirst(UserModel.java:2358)
>
> ** END NESTED EXCEPTION **>
>       Last packet sent to the server was 0 ms ago.,*

I am using the `activejdbc-1.4.14.j7-20180227.053828-4.jar` with `MYSQLDB`

Please help to know why this is happening frequently?? 
And how to fix this error?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Improved formatting and code displays

Answer (score 0):

"Connection reset by peer.." means your application loses a connection to the database. You may have a network or some other connectivity issue. [ActiveJDBC](http://javalite.io/) has nothing to so with it,